# inheritance, or should i use composition?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

Lets say i have a class

```
public class Transfer 
{
    prop1
    prop2
    ....
    public List<SubTransfer> SubTransfers { get; set; }
}
```

Which i get from a function that connects to a database

Now i want to have a class that adds a status, both to the Transfer and to each one of the SubTransfer.

One question is if i should use inheritance here? or composition?

I think inheritance, so im trying to do something like this:

```
public ExtendedSubTransfer : SubTransfer
{
    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }
}

public ExtendedTransfer : Transfer
{
    public StatusEnum Status { get; set;}
}
```

My problem is i dont know how to do that ill get a list of ExtendedSubTransfer when using ExtendedTransfer.

I know i can override SubTransfers using the keyword new like this:

```
public new List<ExtendedSubTransfers> SubTransfers {get; set;}
```

Is it "legit"? Or do you have other suggestions?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The short answer is 'yes it is legit but it depends'.   What do you try to achieve by introducing `StatusEnum` here ? How exactly are you going to use these  `ExtendedSubTransfers` and `ExtendedTransfer` classes? (or what for).

Answer (score 0):

It will compile but it probably isn't going to do what you want.  Keep in mind that `List<ExtendedSubTransfer>` does not extend `List<SubTransfer>`.  For example, if you have any operation that uses the base class you will not get what you want.  To demonstrate, let us pretend the base class has an ID and you want to print the IDs.

```
public void PrintIds()
{
    ExtendedTransfer extendedTransfer = _database.GetExtendedTransfer(...);
    PrintSubTransferIds(extendedTransfer);
}

private PrintSubTransferIds(Transfer transfer)
{
    foreach(var subTransfer in transfer.SubTransfers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(subTransfer.Id);
    }
}
```

The above method will not work unless you do something very strange when loading the items from the database.  For example, if your loading code looks like...

```
public GetExtendedTransfer(...)
{
    ExtendedTransfer result = new ExtendedTransfer();
    List<ExtendedSubTransfer> subTransfers = _connection.QueryForSubTransfers(...);
    result.SubTransfers = subTransfers;
    return result;
}
```

Then it will not work.  It will not print any subtransfer ids because `transfer.SubTransfers` will be an empty list.  Instead you'd have to do something weird when loading from the database like...

```
public GetExtendedTransfer(...)
{
    ExtendedTransfer result = new ExtendedTransfer();
    List<ExtendedSubTransfer> subTransfers = _connection.QueryForSubTransfers(...);
    result.SubTransfers = subTransfers;
    Transfer subtypedResult = result;
    subtypedResult.SubTransfers = subTransfers.Cast<SubTransfer>();
    return result;
}
```

Also, the following case would be a compile time error:

```
public void PrintIds()
{
    ExtendedTransfer extendedTransfer = _database.GetExtendedTransfer(...);
    PrintSubTransferIds(extendedTransfer.SubTransfers);
}

private PrintSubTransferIds(List<SubTransfer> subTransfers)
{
    foreach(var subTransfer in subTransfers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(subTransfer.Id);
    }
}
```

This would fail to compile because `extendedTransfer.SubTransfers` is of type `List<ExtendedSubTransfer>` which cannot be assigned to `List<SubTransfer>`.

### Update: So what should you do?

C# (4.X and above) allows [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233054.aspx) on [certain interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces) such as `IReadOnlyList` (C# 4.5 and above).  Thus you can do...

```
public class Transfer 
{
    public virtual IReadOnlyList<SubTransfer> SubTransfers { get; private set; }
    public void SetSubTransfers(List<SubTransfer> subTransfers)
    {
        SubTransfers = subTransfers;
    }
}

public class ExtendedTransfer
{
    private List<ExtendedSubTransfer> _subTransfers;

    public override IReadOnlyList<SubTransfer> SubTransfers
    {
        get { return _subTransfers; }
    }

    public void SetSubTransfers(List<ExtendedSubTransfer> subTransfers)
    {
        _subTransfers = subTransfers;
    }
}
```

This would be my best attempt at solving your problem.  However, you didn't mention how you are getting your entities from the database.  I don't think `EntityFramework` would be very happy with this field arrangement by default.

Comment: I might not presented my problem like I wanted to. The transfer class is a model that I get from a DAL function that connects to database. The transfer class as only properties, it doesn't connect to the dB itself. My question is mainly about how I inherit the transfer class while inheriting the subtransfer too

Comment: Right, but some code, somewhere, is going to new up an instance of the Transfer class and set some properties on it based on database queries.  If you use `new` then that Transfer class will have two properties with the same name.  Unless that code that is setting properties based on queries is written in the way I describe then it is not going to be expecting that case and will only set one of the two fields.  I don't know how you are mapping queries to instances but if you are using `EntityFramework` then it will not set both fields.